# Understanding what appears to be an instantiation of a method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently trying to understand how well regarded lightbox, ColorBox, works so that I can attempt to make a development to it. However I am struggling with a couple of concepts within the code. The following is where I am stuck:

I have the following function being declared:

```
publicMethod = function() {…}
```

Then after all that this function:

```
publicMethod.init = function() {…}
```

And finally at the end of the script the following command is run:

```
$(publicMethod.init);
```

Now I am not 100% sure what this last command is doing, I assume it is instanciating the method. But I would assume that you should be able to do that by just doing:

publicMethod.init;

Why is it wrapped inside a jQuery parentheses? What is the result of this?

Also, if I am correct in saying that it is instanciating `publicMethod.init`, does that mean that `publicMethod` is being instanciated first before `publicMethod.init`?

Comment: If it's wrapped like that, it may be returning a reference to something in the DOM. What does the function return?

Comment: @minikomi, Like @davin says, passing a function into `$()` adds a document ready event handler; note that `init` isn't called in the OP's code.

Answer (score 3):

Haven't seen the code, but from your description:

`publicMethod = function() { ... }`

Declares and instantiated the function object named `publicMethod`. This obviously happens before declaring `publicMethod.init` since the latter is the `init` property of the object `publicMethod`, so the object `publicMethod` must exist for it to have properties augmented to it.

Regarding the `$(publicMethod.init)`, that line would be executing the jquery function with a function parameter (not sure what "wrapping" means, this is exactly like executing `jQuery(publicMethod.init)` which is a function call).

Maybe it would look more familiar like this: `$(function(){ ... })`, or a similar and almost equivalent form: `$(document).ready(function(){ ... })`.

When the jquery function `$` receives a function as its argument it adds a DOM ready handler, which is a function that will execute when the document is ready. That makes perfect sense with the code you pasted, since it passes the `init` method to be the one to execute when the document is ready.

Comment: So would the code between the curly brackets `{}` on `publicMethod = function() {…}` be processed when `$(publicMethod.init)` is run?

Comment: @Tim, nope, not unless `publicMethod()` is explicitly called. From the code you've shown, it isn't necessarily executed.